# newgeometry command is not working

Tags: geometry

Here is the code I have:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[a4paper, vmargin=1in, top=1in, bottom = 1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    %Put whatever comes before your abstract here
    \lipsum[1]
    \newpage
    
    \newgeometry{top=1in,bottom=1.75in,vmargin=1in} % or whatever only your abstract is supposed to look like
    \section{Abstract}
    \lipsum[1-2]
    \newpage
    
    \restoregeometry % restores the geometry from the preamble
    \lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```

But I do not know why the `newgeometry` command is not working. Could anyone clarify this to me please?

Comment: Because you are using `vmargin` which sets both top and bottom margin. In other words, `top=1in,bottom=1.75in,` are overwritten by `vmargin=1in`

Comment: as Ivan says your margin settings are contradictory but why do you need geometry at all here There doesn't appear to be any need for it in this example.

Comment: I have to personally apologise for this. I messed up vmargin and hmargin in the other question you asked. I thought I had corrected it, but apparently I forgot.

Comment: Just in case it was not obvious to you: v and h are abbreviations of vertical and horizontal. The vertical margins is a collective term for the top and bottom margin.

Comment: thanks you to you all!